# How do I direct navigate to home page instead of index.html in ionic framweork?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I am new to ionic framework 4 with purpose to build android apps. I have generated home page by using command **ionic generate page home** I have tried to direct navigate the home.html instead of index.html in ionic. But have failed. Please help to fix this issue. What portions of code can help to navigate directly home.html

Code :

> app.module.ts

```
 import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import { NgModule, ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';
    import { IonicApp, IonicModule, IonicErrorHandler } from 'ionic-angular';
    import { MyApp } from './app.component';

    import { HelloIonicPage } from '../pages/hello-ionic/hello-ionic';
    import { ItemDetailsPage } from '../pages/item-details/item-details';
    import { ListPage } from '../pages/list/list';

    import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
    import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';

    @NgModule({
      declarations: [
        MyApp,
        HelloIonicPage,
        ItemDetailsPage,
        ListPage
      ],
      imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
      ],
      bootstrap: [IonicApp],
      entryComponents: [
        MyApp,
        HelloIonicPage,
        ItemDetailsPage,
        ListPage
      ],
      providers: [
        StatusBar,
        SplashScreen,
        {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
      ]
    })
    export class AppModule {}
```

> app.component.ts

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

import { Platform, MenuController, Nav } from 'ionic-angular';

import { HelloIonicPage } from '../pages/hello-ionic/hello-ionic';
import { ListPage } from '../pages/list/list';

import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';


@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {
  @ViewChild(Nav) nav: Nav;

  // make HelloIonicPage the root (or first) page
  rootPage = HelloIonicPage;
  pages: Array<{title: string, component: any}>;

  constructor(
    public platform: Platform,
    public menu: MenuController,
    public statusBar: StatusBar,
    public splashScreen: SplashScreen
  ) {
    this.initializeApp();

    // set our app's pages
    this.pages = [
      { title: 'Hello Ionic', component: HelloIonicPage },
      { title: 'My First List', component: ListPage }
    ];
  }

  initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
      this.statusBar.styleDefault();
      this.splashScreen.hide();
    });
  }

  openPage(page) {
    // close the menu when clicking a link from the menu
    this.menu.close();
    // navigate to the new page if it is not the current page
    this.nav.setRoot(page.component);
  }
}
```

Comment: how does your router module look like?

Answer (score 0):

In your app.component.ts:
Inject the router and then navigate to your desired page: (btw: Injections in the constructor should be **private** in 99%)

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

constructor(
  public platform: Platform,
  private router: Router,
) {}

initializeApp() {
  this.platform.ready().then(() => {
    this.router.navigate(['/home']);
  });
}
```

I am assuming the path "/home" exists, because you said, that you generated the home-module with the ionic generator. If not, you have to add it in your  app-routing-module.